# Preserve the param in angular ui router when refreshing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am able to pass Array to other controller using param but when i refresh the param value becomes null. So for this i have used $sessionStorage to preserve my homeArr on reload , but my homeArr is 20000 size and while storing it in $sessionStorage i get Quota Exceeded Exception.

```
.state('home.array'){
url:'/home,
templateUrl:'./home/index.html',
controller:'homeController',
params:{
   homeArr:null
}
```

}

What i should do. please help

Comment: use $localStorage also you can use $rootScope

Comment: When you refresh the param value or refresh the browser?